# Webpack --hot in windows not rebuilding bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack

So I am using webpack-dev-server and its live reload ability. I am on a windows machine. When I change a js file it seems to be reloading the browser but it doesn't rebuild the bundle. Here is my webpack config file

```js
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./app/thirdparty', "./app/app.js"],
  output: {
    filename: "./build/bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/assets/"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: "babel-loader"
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.es6']
  },
  include: path.join(__dirname, 'app')
}
```

I've tried to run it with

`webpack-dev-server`

and

`webpack-dev-server --hot`

But the bundle is not rebuilt

Answer (score 1):

So I solved my own question.
I had a file looking like :

```
output: {
   filename: "./build/bundle.js",
   publicPath: "/assets/"
}
```

I changed it to

```
output : {
    path: path.resolve('build/js'),
    publicPath: "/public/js/",
    filename : "bundle.js",

}
```

Which means it will create a bundle.js that will end up in /build/js/bundle.js
BUT it needs to be referred to in index.html as public/js/bundle.js because of how the publicPath is specified. Also running

```
webpack-dev-server --inline
```

Made everything work. Its obvious once you understand web pack I guess...

Comment: is this still actively watching/re-building for you? I've noticed that webpack seems to do ok for a few re-builds, then stops working so well for me after awhile.

Comment: I only tried 3-4 changes and it was rebuilt... When does it start to NOT work for you? @skplunkerin

Comment: I noticed it won't rebuild unless I reload the page (twice) in the browser, and then save the file again... then it usually rebuilds. This seems to be a problem when I'm making multiple changes to a file... perhaps saving multiple times before I reload the browser page is what's causing the issue? Not sure :/